# Visual Studio error confusion + help please

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I keep getting this in Visual Studio:

```
Compiling...
Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741790 returned from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'.
```

I've re-installed MS VS 3 times already and the code i'm running are project files that work fine on another computer. Am i having some configuration or setup problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your paths under Tools->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories

Any non-existant paths listed (under include files or library files for example) can throw this error.