# error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741515 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compiler-construction, linker

I am using VS2008. (C++ code).  I am getting the error when compiling:

> error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741515 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'

I tried all the options available in net including one of the stackoverflow link 
[Visual Studio error confusion + help please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145469/visual-studio-error-confusion-help-please)

1. Tried shortening the path of my source solution by placing directly inside C drive.
2. Tried Removing any VS plugins. Tools -> Addin Manager.

My codebase is fine because the same solution is compiling fine on other machines. When I copied the solution to a particular m/c I am getting this error.

It has custom build steps, post build steps. But they are all correct because its working on other computers.

Answer (score 3):

0xC0000135 (hex -1073741515) can be found in NtStatus.h

Its meaning is STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. Try to look on your cl.exe with [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: +1 for a brilliant suggestion, that would have never crossed my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your settings of Visual Studio? It is available in Tools->Import and Export Settings. Setting it to Visual C++ Development Settings might do the trick. I know it have helped others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this path to the environment PATH variable:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE

some of the dependencies of the cl.exe are lying in this directory, which were unresolved.